# Is there an instrument for measuring language vitality?

Tags: language-change, sociolinguistics, endangered-languages

I currently am doing an anthropological research in a community where two languages are spoken. A community language X, which is the language historically spoken by the ancestors of that community, and Spanish, which is the national language.

My overall impression is that Spanish is in the porcess of replacing X as the language of this specific community. (As far as I have noticed, children speak—only—in Spanish among themselves, for instance, when they play.) However, you can find plenty of adult X speakers (mostly older than 30) in the community.

Instead of trusting my 'overall impression', though, I'd rather do a randomised poll with an appropriate instrument that can measure 'language vitality'. Hence, I would like to ask whether there are well-validated instruments for this purpose (or at least that have been applied in previous studies).

Given what I said in the second paragraph, I'm aware I probably don't need to conduct a poll to be sure that language X is dying in this community. However, such a poll may reveal interesting things about this process.